# Render curves as hair particles?

Tags: python, bezier-curves, hair, optimization

I tried first to place hair particles with Python but Blender never let me do so, so here's the question the other way around: it is possible to pass curves to Cycles without meshing them and to treat them as hair particles?

If I can avoid to mesh curves and use hair instead, then I can load thousands (even hundreds of thousands) of curves and benefit from the way hair is handled in Blender...